# Why does a superclass requires services from subclass in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, dependency-injection, frontend

Today i came across this piece of code in Angular

```
export class ContentFormComponent extends FormBase {

...

constructor(
  private authService: AuthService,
  private apiService: ApiService,
  private segmentService: SegmentService
) { super(authService, segmentService) }

...

}
```

the superclass `FormBaseComponent` declaration looks like this:

```
export abstract class FormBase {

...

constructor (
   protected authService: AuthService,
   protected segmentService: SegmentService
) { }

...

}
```

My question is, why does this abstract class requires services from subclasses?
My understanding is that services in Angular are Singleton, meaning there only exists a single instance of services throughout the whole app. Also, both of those services are provided in root.

Why can't the `FormBase` class simply inject those services by DI in the constructor definition? isn't it redundant?

Please be gentle, i'm pretty new at all of this, i'm just trying to learn lol

Comment: Constructors don't work like that: when a class is subclassed, then the subclass becomes the gatekeeper of the superclass' constructor and _all_ of the superclass' dependencies now have to go through the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

For the actual answer of the question please refer to the comment of Dai.

> Constructors don't work like that: when a class is subclassed, then the subclass becomes the gatekeeper of the superclass' constructor and all of the superclass' dependencies now have to go through the subclass.

My answer is about to offer you an approach without having to pass those services to the parent. This approach is possible as of **Angular 14**.

Here you can move the injection of the services to **outside of the constructor** with the **inject** function. As a result the subsclasses don't need to take care of those services to pass.

```
export abstract class FormBase {
  protected authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);
  protected segmentService: SegmentService = inject(SegmentService);
}

export class ContentFormComponent extends FormBase {
  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { super(); }
}
```